# Open a specific file with my android application

Tags: android, android-manifest, react-native, manifest

I tried to open my android app when I click on a file with the extension of "play" (someFileName.play).

My problem is that it does not matter on what kind of file I click, it gives the the option to open it with my app.

This is my "Manifest.xml":

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.play">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
         <!-- custom file start -->
        <intent-filter
          android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <!-- change custom file extension -->
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.play" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- custom file end -->
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Need help to fix it, please help.

Comment: did you try removing `android:mimeType` and `android:host`?

Comment: @user1506104 yes but still same problem

Comment: also, are you trying to open the file from a file browser app? file an http link?

Comment: @user1506104  I downloaded the file from the internet and open it from download folder

Comment: I see. try adding this to your filter: `<data android:scheme="file" />` and/or `<data android:scheme="content" />`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to:

```
        <!-- change custom file extension -->
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" 
              android:host="*" 
              android:pathPattern=".*\\.play" />
```